# Vector Drawables Android 23.3.0

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I got '23.3.0' support library version, can when attempting to do this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/abc"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
```

The drawable is not appearing in the device running api 21. As a matter of fact, my app has min Api 21, and even in the android studio preview, only N Preview Api 23 will actually draw the background. I have never had any problems with this with normal ImageViews. The vector is this one:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="414dp"
        android:height="100dp"
        android:viewportWidth="414"
        android:viewportHeight="100">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFD50000"
        android:pathData="M 0,0 414,0 414,65 0,100 0,0"/>
</vector>
```

Any idea why it is not appearing?

Comment: Not quite sure what do you want to draw with this path data, but it is wrong: it doesn't have "draw line" instructions, just "move to" instructions. If you open this drawable in Android Studio then the preview will be empty too. Have a look at the SVG specifications regarding how to assemble your vector data: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely should update your support library:

> Android Support Library 23.4.0 available now
>
> This release of the Android Support Library fixes a number of bugs in
>   Support v4, AppCompat, Design, and Vector Drawable Compat. See the
>   revisions page (https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) for a full list of closed
>   issues.

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/B7QhFkWZ6YX

Comment: tried that already. its the same. not showing. Since i have minApi 21, i'm not doing anything concerning vector drawables at all, i do not use srcCompat i use everything like normal png and everything is working. But in this case, the vector is not showing.